# Calculating LL(1) grammar

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers, parsers

I am trying to calculate the First and Follow of the following grammar

```
S->ABC
A->Aa
A->aB
B->Bb
B-> epsilon
C-> Cc
C-> Epsilon
```

I have calculated the firsts and it is all good

```
Follow(A) = {a,b,c,$}
```

What is confusing me is the follow of B, I get `Follow(B) = Follow(A)`
But on the other hand, I have a solution for the grammar that states that the `follow(B) = {b,c,$}`

So which one is the right one?

Comment: Why do you think that $Follow(A)$ should be the same as $Follow(B)$?

Comment: According to a rule that says                                            * For any production rule A → αB,
Follow(B) = Follow(A)

Answer (score 1):

It is evident that $B$ can be followed by $a$  — in other words, that $a\in \text{FOLLOW}(B)$ — as shown by the partial derivation

$$\begin{align}S&\to A B C&(S\to ABC)\\
&\to  AaBC &(A\to Aa)\\&\to aBaBC&(A\to aB) \\
\end{align}$$

So the answer provided does not correspond to this grammar.